# Flex collapsible field group control

Tags: apache-flex, controls, sidebar

I am trying to make a side panel in a Flex application that would hold a bunch of properties of a selected object. The number of properties may become huge, but they all fall into some certain categories.

For that, I am looking for a flex control that would be like a collapsible field group. Or like an accordion that can have multiple open panels at a time. Do you know, where can I get one?

**UPDATE:** I want something like the second example on the following page: http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/dynamic.html

Thanks,
Artem.

Comment: Because I want more than one group to be open at a time

Answer (score 1):

http://www.flexdownloads.com/#view=detail;vstr1=19

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for some sort of tree component.  Flex actually has one of those and you should probably take a look at it.

This is a good link to see what controls are included in flex http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html

Comment: I want something like the second example in the URL below:
http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/dynamic.html